# Why Gambit game theory code is not ruuning using python script?

Tags: python, django, game-theory

game1.py:

```
import gambit
import gambit.nash

def play():
    g=gambit.read_game("4X3.nfg")
    solver=gambit.nash.ExternalLogitSolver()
    solver.solve(g)
    return

play()
```

this is my code showing error that:

`/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-5.7-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py:1049: UserWarning: /home/raja/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).`

if i run the same code in python console not giving any error working properly..

Comment: yeah got it just assigned the solver.solve(g) output to an array...

Comment: just change the permissions of the folder .python-eggs for group and others to none. and the message you showed is a warning not an error

Comment: hi Sainath, do you know how to run stochastic games using gambit game theory tool....?

Comment: did you read this paper https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/kryukov/HomotopyGuide.pdf ?

Comment: no i will read now thank you so much...

Comment: hi boss this is using Fortran right.Can you please tell me  is there any other solution using python,gambit

Comment: hi sainath if you have any references for stochastic games please link here....